# Why are there no version 11.x images listed against the node image on Docker Hub?

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerhub

Why are there no version 11.x images listed against the node image on Docker Hub?

I expected to find the version 11 images in between the 10 and 12 but they appear to be missing: https://hub.docker.com/_/node/

Answer (score 0):

This is due to security vulnerabilities, details can be found here: https://snyk.io/blog/node-js-release-fixes-a-critical-http-security-vulnerability/